# PyQt5 uses Pyglet's event loop automatically?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyglet

Why does this code work?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
import pyglet

app = QApplication([])
w = QWidget()
w.show()

pyglet.app.run()
```

PyQt somehow uses Pyglet's event loop, why and how much can I rely on this? I am not skilled enough to debug it. This works with much more complex PyQt5 apps too, all events are handled properly.

I'm on windows 10, python 3.7.2.

Comment: Are you sure that code works? Can you change the size of the widget? Can you move it?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. I've tried to change `sys.exit(app.exec())` to `import pyglet; pyglet.app.run()` in one of the complex PyQt5 apps I've written before and it still runs ok. I can actually add a pyglet window with some content and both windows handle all events correctly too.

Comment: It seems strange to me, I would expect it to freeze or block (I'm not an expert in pyglet), I have tested it in Linux observing that the window freezes as expected.